# Users listed on Badge slightly misaligned

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On the [gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail) badge [page](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/badges/191/gmail), this is seen, Rebecca is lower than Al and Senseful.

[image: Misaligned listing]

`.mod-flair` span seems to be pushing Rebecca down.

Seen in the following browsers

- Google Chrome Mac 12.0.742.91
- Safari Version 5.0.5 (6533.21.1)
- Firefox Mac 3.6.17
- Safari mobile iPhone

Also the same is seen for

- [Convention badge](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/badges/199/convention)
- [Beta](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/badges/30?page=3)
- Well basically any page that is listed like this

Comment: Unacceptable! q:

Comment: Seems to me the easiest solution is to take mod privilege away from Rebecca... j/k. I'll fix.

Comment: I've checked on Rebecca's alignment and noticed that she's still off balance. @Jin, can you have a look at this once more. When all is said and done, please tag as such!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix will be in the next production build, sometime after midnight tonight EST or tomorrow.

Comment: Alignment is OK.